# How do I connect to a network location on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-leopard

I am given this network location:

```
afp://something.ca/Public/
```

I'm currently on Leopard, what GUI app should I use to connect to the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **Finder**'s *Go...Connect to Server* menu item.  It's keyboard Command-K when Finder has focus.